# cannot embedded element loaded from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm new to jquery ajax, I did my best to solve my problem with ajax. Basically, I'm loading external json data to set as link or button to do some action. However, after ajax load, it disable other jquery functions. Currently, I'm testing simple action, but later on, the action would be ajax load.

After my search on the internet about Ajax, I need to use jquery 'when' for multiple ajax and I need to use jquery 'delegate'. Is this the selution to my case?

This is simple of my work

HTML and js

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "../JsonObj/mnb.json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.nav_buttons.nav_button.length  ; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0 && i < data.nav_buttons.nav_button.length)
            {
                $("nav").append("<h1>" + "|" + "</h1>");
            }
            $("nav").append("<a href='" + data.nav_buttons.nav_button[i].url + "'>" + "<h1 id='citvnmb"
                + i + "' class='citvnmbcls'>" + data.nav_buttons.nav_button[i].name + "</h1>" + "</a>");
        }
    },
    error: function ()
    {
        alert("unbale to load main nav buttons ");
    }
});

$("#citvnmb0").click(function () {

    alert("test");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <nav>
        

        
    </nav>
```

mnb.json

```
{
"nav_buttons": {
    "nav_button": [

        { "name": "Kitchen",      "url": "#"  },
        { "name": "Home",         "url": "#"  },

    ]
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an element dynamically, you must use `on()` to access your element:

```
$(document).on("click","#citvnmb0" , function () {
    alert("test");
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this  really helps. Would I face a new problem if I load ajax data inside this action? on the other way. Do I need to use jQuery '.when' to avoid additional problem?

Answer (score 0):

I want to make sure your json data is getted exactly.
I have 2 solution

1. set attribute onclick in tag
2. Use dynamic on click jquery

   $("#citvnmb0").on("click",function () {
   alert("test");
   });